# Scipy.signal does not import unless preceeded by an import of pyplot

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, scipy

This is so very weird. This fails in two different ways on each import

```
>>> import scipy.signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.signal
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 282, in <module>
    from .bsplines import *
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\bsplines.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, gamma
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 627, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
  File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:26242)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> import scipy.signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.signal
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 282, in <module>
    from .bsplines import *
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\bsplines.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, gamma
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 629, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\Users\ewwieser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma, psi, zeta,
ImportError: cannot import name 'ellipkm1'
```

Whereas this works just fine (in a fresh shell):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> import scipy.signal
>>>
```

My setup is:

- Python 3.5.1 x64 on windows
- Numpy 1.11.0 (installed from [`~gohlke`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))
- Scipy 0.17.1 (installed from [`~gohlke`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))
- Matplotlib 1.5.1 (installed directly with `pip install matplotlib`)

Why do the imports depend on one another? How is that even possible?

Comment: That seems very very wrong.  How did you install everything?  The failures in scipy are coming out of the compiled modules which makes me think your installation is broken.

Comment: @tcaswell: Updated with installation instructions

Comment: It seems that `matplotlib.colorbar`, which is used by `pyplot`, is sufficient here

Comment: Following the chain to the end of the python, `import matplotlib._path` is enough

Comment: Try install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-c), which is required by scipy. The official matplotlib binaries include the Visual C++ runtime DLLs, which are loaded into the process by `import matplotlib._path` such that `scipy.special._ufuncs` can find/use those DLLs.

Comment: @cgohlke: So matplotlib comes with the dlls and adds them to the library path, whereas scipy expects them to already be on the path somewhere?

Comment: That did fix the problem